# How do I get virtualenv to prefer its local libraries over global libraries

Tags: python, virtualenv

I need to use python on a big server where I don't have root access.  I want to use a newer version of numpy than the one that is installed globally on the machine.  `virtualenv` is designed exactly for this purpose, and I create my virtual environment and activate it with the following commands:

```
virtualenv my_personal_python
source my_personal_python/bin/activate
```

I then install the new version of the library that I'm interested in using

```
pip install numpy==1.6.0
```

The problem is that when I now import numpy it still imports the outdated global version, not the one install in the virtual environment's `my_personal_python/lib/python2.6/site-packacges` directory.

I am already aware of one possible solution, the --no-site-packages flag, as in:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages my_personal_python
```

When I use this flag then the import behaves as I desire.  But I don't want to use this flag because I do not want to re-install all packages locally, I just want to override a couple of them.

(I'm using python 2.6, virtualenv 1.6.1, and the PYTHONPATH variable on my machine is not set.)

**Update**  Even if I add the site-packages directory from the virtual environment to the beginning of the python path, numpy does not get imported from this location (although other packages are imported from this location).  Maybe this problem is specific to numpy and does not occur with packages in general.

Comment: AFAIK, it should work as you expect. Maybe it's a bug in the old version of virtualenv that's presumably installed on that computer...

Comment: not sure if this is the issue, but does pip know to use the activated virtual environment?  Check and see if numpy 1.6.0 is installed in your global site-packages.

Comment: pip does know how to use the virtual environment, and it properly installed version 1.6.0 to the virtual environment's site-packages directory.  The global version of numpy is 1.4.0.

Comment: @conradlee, Having this same problem two years later. What was the solution???

Comment: Same here, in 2015.  My virtualenv paths are much later than `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` in `sys.path()`. Has there been a solution since that does not involve changing the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Double check a few things.

`which python`

`which pip`

Now that you are sure you are running the right one, start python and:

```
import sys
print "\n".join(sys.path)
```

Then exit python and type `echo $PATH` followed by `echo $PYTHONPATH`
I suspect that the problem will be visible and if you cannot fix it by setting `PYTHONPATH` then you can likely do it with the `site` module.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

My `which python` and `which pip` were exactly correct but the `sys.path` was wrong. My virtualenv is in `~/virtualenvs/envy`. Originally I was doing:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/virtualenvs/envy/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

but this still was importing the system-wide package instead of my virtualenv one. BUT I watched [this PyCon talk on virtualenv](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2011-reverse-engineering-ian-bicking-s-brain-inside-pip-and-virtualenv-4899496) and decided to try:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/virtualenvs/envy/lib/python2.7:$PYTHONPATH
```

Notice the lack of `site-packages` in the second option. And this actually worked! I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

One more solution to this problem (helped me, at least):  In my `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth`, there were (IMHO unnecessary) lines like `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.  Removing these lines helped, maybe they were left over from much older times, when easy_install still did stranger things.